# spread function using symbols in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a very simple dataset with two variables.

```
data <- data.frame(
             ID = c("A","A","B","C","D","D"),
             Service = c("Shop","Online","Shop","Online","Online","Shop"))
```

I want to use the `spread()` function on `Service`, but rather than `spread` by `ID`, I want the resulting table to include a "Y" symbol to indicate that `ID` operates that specific service. For example:

```
  ID       Shop    Online
  A         Y         Y
  B         Y         - 
  C         -         Y
  D         Y         Y
```

However, the `spread()` function won't work by just giving a key, so is there a way I can do this using the existing `spread` function or do I have to use something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a new column first

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(spread_col = "Y") %>% 
  spread(Service, spread_col, fill = "-")
#  ID Online Shop
#1  A      Y    Y
#2  B      -    Y
#3  C      Y    -
#4  D      Y    Y
```

(This might be a duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format))

---

You could also use `dcast` from `data.table` or `reshape2`:

```
reshape2::dcast(
  data,
  ID ~ Service,
  fun.aggregate = function(x) replace(x, x == x, "Y"),
  fill = "-"
)
```

Comment: Sorry just one problem I'm finding now: I noticed I still have duplicate rows in my dataset, e.g. there are two rows for ID "A" and they are not merged. I keep getting Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows. Any ideas?

Comment: No worries, I've just figured out that my main dataset had a couple of exact-match rows. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `base`.

data: (use a factor variable)

```
data <- data.frame(
    ID = c("A","A","B","C","D","D"),
    Service = factor(c("Shop","Online","Shop","Online","Online","Shop")), levels = c("Online","Shop"))
```

code:

```
ans<-
do.call(
    rbind, tapply(data$Service, data$ID, table)
)

ans[ans == 1] = "Y"
ans[ans == 0] = "-"
```

result:

```
#> ans
#  Online Shop
#A "Y"    "Y" 
#B "-"    "Y" 
#C "Y"    "-" 
#D "Y"    "Y" 
#>
```